# SoftLayer API: Order Security Certificate CSR validation

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the following openssl command to genereate CSR:

```
openssl genrsa -out mytestdomain.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key mytestdomain.key -out mytestdomain.csr
```

I try to place a Security Certificate order from SoftLayer customer portal using the aboved mytestdomain.csr value under the "Enter Certificate Signing Rquest (CSR) , I got an error msg :

> "Must match CSR Base64 encoded PEM Format 
>   ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST---   Base64 Encoded String
>   --End CERTIFICATE REQUEST ---

How to use openssl to generate Base64 encoded PEM CSR ?

If I enter a correct csr value from a sample file,  I can see SoftLayer does a validation request as: 
https://control.softlayer.com/security/sslorders/validatecsr

and the response shows valid email address, country such as : 
{"success":true,"result":{"X":"XX","xx":"XXXX, Europe","L":"XXXX City","O":"My Test","OU":"VPN","XX":"mytest.com","emailAddress":"test@mytest.com"}}

Question 2:  Which method can I use to validate and extract information from CSR, similar to what the SoftLayer customer portal use?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your questions:

**Question 1:** I followed the steps in this link and it works successfully for me:

https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-support/csr-generation/ssl-certificate-mod-ssl.html

This will generate .key and .csr files. You should specify the .csr file content for CSR.

**Question 2:** The [SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request::validateCsr](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request/validateCsr) method will help to validate the CSR.

Here a PHP example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Validate Csr
 *
 * This script allows you to validate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) required 
 * for an SSL certificate with the certificate authority (CA). This method sends the CSR, 
 * the length of the subscription in months, the certificate type, and the server type for 
 * validation against requirements of the CA. Returns true if valid.
 *
 * Important manual pages:
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request/validateCsr
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/license>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 */
require_once '\vendor\autoload.php';

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API username and apiKey
 * @var string
 * @var string
 */
$apiUsername = 'set me';
$apiKey = 'set me';

/**
 * The encoded CSR data string
 * @var string
 */
$csr = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----";

/**
 * The product item identifier for the type of SSL certificate
 * E.g: Item Id: 965 Description: RapidSSL - 2 year
 * @var int
 */
$itemId = 965;

 /**
 * The type of server in which the certificate will be installed
 * @var string
 */
$serverType = "apache2";

/**
 * The length of the certificate subscription desired in months. Typically 12 or 24 months
 * @var int
 */
$validityMonths = 24;

// Create a SoftLayer API client object for "SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request" service
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);

try {
    $result = $client->validateCsr($csr, $validityMonths, $itemId, $serverType);
    print_r($result);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die('Unable to validated CSR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I hope this information can help you.

Comment: Ruber, thank you for the information and sample code.  I tried to run validate csr php code locally with the new csr value I generated by following the link https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-support/csr-generation/ssl-certificate-mod-ssl.html.  I can see the method SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request ->validateCsr($csr, $validityMonths, $itemId, $serverType) returns only a boolean value "1" if there's no error.   It doesn't return any detailed information about the CSR such as Country Name, emailAddress, State or Province Name.  Is there API I can use to get the CSR info ?

Comment: I can see SoftLayer customer portal order SSL does a validation request as: https://control.softlayer.com/security/sslorders/validatecsr
The response data showing valid email address, country such as : {"success":true,"result":{"X":"XX","xx":"XXXX, Europe","L":"XXXX City","O":"My Test","OU":"VPN","XX":"mytest.com","emailAddress":"test@mytest.com"}}   .  The method SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request->validateCsr only return boolean value without detailed information about CSR.  Any method can return me data like the response from https://control.softlayer.com/security/sslorders/validatecsr

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not an SoftLayer API method that will help to decode CSR. Control Portal has some internal methods which help to decode CSRs. Take a look the following reference, probably it will help to decode CSRs:
[OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php)

Comment: Thx. I generated my RSA certificate using "openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mytestserver.key -out mytestserver.csr".  The php lib "openssl_x509_parse" can only parse/return info for X509 certificate, won't return info for rsa cerfiticate.   For SoftLayer  API, it seems the SoftLayer_Security_Certificate_Request->validateCs(...) only returns "true" for RSA csr, gives error for x509 certificate. Does SoftLayer only allow RSA type of CSR ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the types of CSR that are supported by SoftLayer, you can submit a ticket if you want more information about it. 
However, if you want to validate the CSR, you can try with this: [SSL Decoder](https://github.com/RaymiiOrg/ssl-decoder), it is based on PHP. Also I extracted a little part of code from there, to get the result that you are expecting, try with this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Function get_sans_from_csr
 */
function get_sans_from_csr($csr) {
  global $random_blurp;
  global $timeout;
  $sans = array();
  //openssl_csr_get_subject doesn't support SAN names.
  $filename = "C:/Csr/tmp/csr-" . $random_blurp . "-" . gen_uuid() . ".csr.pem";
  $write_csr = file_put_contents($filename, $csr);
  if($write_csr !== FALSE) {
    $openssl_csr_output = trim(shell_exec("timeout " . $timeout . " openssl req -noout -text -in " . $filename . " | grep -e 'DNS:' -e 'IP:'"));
  }
  unlink($filename);
  if($openssl_csr_output) {

    $csr_san_dns = explode("DNS:", $openssl_csr_output);
    $csr_san_ip = explode("IP:", $openssl_csr_output);
    if(count($csr_san_dns) > 1) {
      foreach ($csr_san_dns as $key => $value) {
        if($value) {
          $san = trim(str_replace(",", "", str_replace("DNS:", "", $value)));
          array_push($sans, $san);
        }
      }
    }
    if(count($csr_san_ip) > 1) {
      foreach ($csr_san_ip as $key => $value) {
        if($value) {
          $san = trim(str_replace(",", "", str_replace("IP:", "", $value)));
          array_push($sans, $san);
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  if(count($sans) >= 1) {
    return $sans;
  }
}

/**
 * Function csr_parse_json
 */
function csr_parse_json($csr) {
  // if csr or cert is pasted in form this function parses the csr or it send the cert to cert_parse.
  global $random_blurp;
  global $timeout;
  $result = array();
  if (strpos($csr, "BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST") !== false) { 
    $cert_data = openssl_csr_get_public_key($csr);
    $cert_details = openssl_pkey_get_details($cert_data);
    $cert_key = $cert_details['key'];
    $cert_subject = openssl_csr_get_subject($csr);
    $result["subject"] = $cert_subject;
    $result["key"] = $cert_key;
    $result["details"] = $cert_details; 
    if ($cert_details) {
      $result["csr_pem"] = $csr;
      $sans = get_sans_from_csr($csr);
      if(count($sans) > 1) {
        $result["csr_sans"] = $sans;
      }
    }
  } elseif (strpos($csr, "BEGIN CERTIFICATE") !== false) { 
    $result = cert_parse_json($csr, null, null, null, null, true);
  } else {
    $result = array("error" => "data not valid csr");
  }
  return $result;
}

/**
 * Function gen_uuid
 */
function gen_uuid() {
  //from stack overflow.
  return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
    // 32 bits for "time_low"
    mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
    // 16 bits for "time_mid"
    mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
    // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
    // four most significant bits holds version number 4
    mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
    // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
    // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
    // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
    mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
    // 48 bits for "node"
    mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
  );
}

// Define your csr
$data = csr_parse_json("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----");
// Print whole result
print_r($data);

// Print "subject" property from the result
print_r($data["subject"]);

?>
```

All the methods used in the script were extracted from: [SSL Decoder](https://github.com/RaymiiOrg/ssl-decoder)